# Control StackNavigator outside of the animated scene

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

EDIT: I understand my problem and solution so I'm rephrasing my question, followed by an answer.

A normal `StackNavigator` and screen with navigation looks like this:

```
class ExampleScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate, state } = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    const exampleTitle = state.params.title;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{exampleTitle}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Click"
          onPress={() => {
            navigate('Example', { exampleTitle: 'foo' })
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const ExampleNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Example: { screen: ExampleScreen }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Example',
  initialRouteParams: { exampleTitle: 'bar' }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => ExampleNavigator);
```

I would like to access the `navigation` object outside of `ExampleScreen#render` so that it isn't part of the `CardStack` animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding another screen to render `ExampleNavigator` and
setting a `ref` attribute on `ExampleNavigator`. The `navigation` object and
route params need to be accessed slightly differently, but I'll explain below in comments throughout the code.

```
class ExampleScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { state } = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    const exampleTitle = state.params.title;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{exampleTitle}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const ExampleNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Example: { screen: ExampleScreen }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Example',
  initialRouteParams: { exampleTitle: 'bar' }
});

// my solution
class RootScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // makes sure _onPress has the correct context when clicked
    this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    // flex: 1 is set to make the navigator visible. you wont see the navigator
    // without this.
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ExampleNavigator ref='nav' />
        <Button title='Click' onPress={this._onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _onPress() {
    // read navigate and state from _navigation
    const { navigate, state } = this.refs.nav._navigation;
    const { routes, index } = state;
    // read scene params through the route of the index passed in state
    const params = routes[index].params;
    const exampleTitle = params.exampleTitle + ' clicked';

    // use the navigate method as your normally would
    navigate('Example', {exampleTitle});
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => RootScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what I would like to do is very similar, if not identical, to this. I don't understand why this isn't so common (extracting behaviour from a component and allowing higher level components to define behaviour across a set of components, and in this case define all navigation behaviour) as to be supported without having to use refs.

An ideal solution would seem to be:

```
class ExampleScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate, state } = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    const exampleTitle = state.params.title;

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{exampleTitle}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Click"
          onPress=state.params.onPress
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const ExampleNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Example: { screen: ExampleScreen }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Example',
  initialRouteParams: {
    exampleTitle: 'bar',
    onPress: () => {XXX.navigate('Example', { exampleTitle: 'foo' })}
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Example', () => ExampleNavigator);
```

with navigate being available somehow within StackNavigator initialRouteParams.

Am I also missing something here in terms of an easy solution to what seems like a commonly expected design pattern?